# How to get parse tree from CoreNLP server's returned string in python?

Tags: stanford-nlp, corenlp-server

I'm using pycorenlp with the corenlp server. I can get the parse tree in the string format. But can I get it as a tree like the NLTK library?

```
from pycorenlp import StanfordCoreNLP
import pprint
import nltk

nlp = StanfordCoreNLP('http://localhost:9000')

text = ('Purgrug Vobter and Juklog Qligjar vruled into the Battlefield. Vobter was about to Hellfire. Juklog Qligjar started kiblaring.')

output = nlp.annotate(text, properties={
'annotators': 'tokenize,ssplit,pos,depparse,parse',
'outputFormat': 'json'
})


print [s['parse'] for s in output['sentences']]
```

Output:

```
[u'(ROOT\r\n  (S\r\n    (NP (NNP Purgrug) (NNP Vobter)\r\n      (CC and)\r\n      (NNP Juklog) (NNP Qligjar))\r\n    (VP (VBD vruled)\r\n      (PP (IN into)\r\n        (NP (DT the) (NN Battlefield))))\r\n    (. .)))', u'(ROOT\r\n  (S\r\n    (NP (NNP Vobter))\r\n    (VP (VBD was)\r\n      (ADJP (IN about)\r\n        (PP (TO to)\r\n          (NP (NNP Hellfire)))))\r\n    (. .)))', u'(ROOT\r\n  (S\r\n    (NP (NNP Juklog) (NNP Qligjar))\r\n    (VP (VBD started)\r\n      (S\r\n        (VP (VBG kiblaring))))\r\n    (. .)))']
```

Answer (score 6):

Import tree from nltk :

```
from nltk.tree import *
```

Next, for

```
a = [u'(ROOT\r\n  (S\r\n    (NP (NNP Purgrug) (NNP Vobter)\r\n      (CC and)\r\n      (NNP Juklog) (NNP Qligjar))\r\n    (VP (VBD vruled)\r\n      (PP (IN into)\r\n        (NP (DT the) (NN Battlefield))))\r\n    (. .)))', u'(ROOT\r\n  (S\r\n    (NP (NNP Vobter))\r\n    (VP (VBD was)\r\n      (ADJP (IN about)\r\n        (PP (TO to)\r\n          (NP (NNP Hellfire)))))\r\n    (. .)))', u'(ROOT\r\n  (S\r\n    (NP (NNP Juklog) (NNP Qligjar))\r\n    (VP (VBD started)\r\n      (S\r\n        (VP (VBG kiblaring))))\r\n    (. .)))']

Tree.fromstring(a[0]).pretty_print()
```

And that's all.

[image: result]